# Confirm 2 password fields via jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, passwords

I am trying to find a small script where while typing in the two password fields and if the passwords do not match then the script will specify... I also hope to do this without having to click the Submit button.

Here are my two fields:

```
<input name="password" type="password" id="password-1" maxlength="30" placeholder="Password Must Be 5-30 Characters" class="text-input required password">
<input name="password" type="password" id="password-2" placeholder="Repeat Password" class="text-input required password">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change the input field names,

```
<input name="password1" type="password" id="password-1" maxlength="30" placeholder="Password Must Be 5-30 Characters" class="text-input required password">
<input name="password2" type="password" id="password-2" placeholder="Repeat Password" class="text-input required password">
```

and use the following script,

```
$("#password-2").change(function(){
     if($(this).val() != $("#password-1").val()){
               alert("values do not match");
               //more processing here
     }
});
```

If you want to use more functions, you should think of using a jquery plugin like  [jquery Validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

Comment: thanks for this. Just missing the closing parenthesis for the `if` argument. I tried to edit but apparently to edit the correction needs to be more than 6 characters...haha. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like:

```
$('.password').change(function(){
      if($("#password-1").val() == $("#password-2").val()){
            /* they match */
      }else{
            /* they are different */
      }
 });
```

this will hook onto the class you put on both these fields, and whenever somebody changes **either** field it will perform this check.

you could also use `$('input[type=password]')` if you didn't have those classes...

here's some further reading:

http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/check-passwords-using-jquery/

http://bmharwani.com/blog/2010/11/12/matching-the-password-and-confirm-password-fields-in-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

you can get this out of the box with the [jquery validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation).  There are lots of docs and tutorials for you to follow including those for making sure two fields match.